# Show same IDs together but ORDER BY timestamp

Tags: sql

I have the following rows:

```
Person Age timestamp
```

Now I want that all rows to be sorted like this:
Order by timestamp, but Persons with the same Age should be grouped together!

[image]

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the table(s) involved, some sample data and the expected output (_formatted_ text please [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) Also: tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres? Oracle?, DB2?, Firebird?)

Comment: So in case of two persons with the same age - Who will be shown?

Comment: `order by Age, timestamp`?

Comment: Priority have timestamp: First I want to see the Peroson with the oldest timestamp and after this person I want to see all Persons with the same age like the first person equal with witch timestamp. Then I want to see the

Comment: what rdbms are you working with?

Comment: SQL and PHP together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to order by the largest time for each age.  Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions, so you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by max(timestamp) over (partition by age) desc,
         age,
         timestamp desc;
```

In the "databases" that don't (MS Access, SQLite, MySQL):

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select age, max(timestamp) as maxts
      from t
      group by age
     ) tt
     on t.age = tt.age
order by maxts desc, age, timestamp desc;
```

Comment: How can I connect it with my tabel named "persons"?

Comment: OK. Thanks! "t" ist "persons"

Comment: @JürgenHohlkopf . . . Probably.  The question doesn't mention the table name.